# python-click: Option working on group but specified after sub command

Tags: python, python-click

I read [in the documentation for Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/commands/#passing-parameters) that

> options and arguments for a specific command have to be specified after the command name itself, but before any other command names.

Is there any advanced technique to overcome this limitation?
In my application I have a group with several subcommands. I'd like to configure logging using an option (e.g. `--silent`) only once in the "main" group command. This can be done with

```
bash> cli --silent sub1
```

but placing the option before the sub command is not nice (breaking change for the users of my application). Instead I would like to implement:

```
bash> cli sub1 --silent # does not work, see the example below
```

I currently configure logging in each sub command, but this leads to code duplication.

Here is an example implementing a `cli` group with two sub commands `sub1` and `sub2`

```
import click

def add_options(func):
    func = click.option(
        "--silent",
        "log",
        flag_value="silent",
    )(func)
    # more options e.g. "--verbose"
    return func


def configure_logging(log):
    print(f"Configuring logging using '{log}'")

@click.group()
@add_options
def cli(log):
    print("main")
    configure_logging(log)


@cli.command()
def sub1():
    print("sub1")

@cli.command()
@add_options
def sub2(log):
    print("sub2")
    configure_logging(log)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Examples:

```
> python test.py sub1 --silent
main
..
Error: No such option: --silent   # bad
> python test.py sub2 --silent
main
Configuring logging using 'None'  # bad
sub2
Configuring logging using 'silent'
> python test.py --silent sub1    # ok, but not what I want
main
Configuring logging using 'silent'
sub1
> #python test.py --silent sub1    # also not what I want
> #python test.py --silent sub2    # also not what I want
> #python test.py --silent sub2 --silent # also not what I want
```